# Reference request: the category of adjunctions between posets as categories that induce a partiuclar monad

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, monads, galois-connections

I am interested in the category $A$ of adjunctions that induce a monad $c : C \to C$ where $C$ is a poset. (The description of $A$ is in a [previous math.se post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/392004/20552).) For a general $C$, of course, $A$ could be very complicated, but I would imagine that for a poset $C$ it is more feasible to give an explicit description of $A$.

Is there a good source from which I can learn about such a description of this category?  Even if this is not possible for general posets, is it feasible for special posets (lattices,  locales, etc)?

Comment: Can you please give a precise definition of $A$? What are the objects, what are the morphisms?

Comment: I believe the intention is that $A$ is the category in which the Kleisli and Eilenberg-Moore splittings are initial and terminal, respectively? I actually can't think of any reference that deals with these categories in any detail.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I meant that category.  (Is the category that I described not that category?)

Comment: @pteromys - It's the only such category I know, but I didn't want to put words in your mouth in case there was another I wasn't aware of :)

Comment: If $C$ and $D$ are posets, an adjunction between them is just a *Galois connection* between $C$ and $D^{op}$, and the monads are exactly the *closure operators*: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Galois+connection, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closure+operator

Comment: @Berci Thank you for your clarification.  I used categorical terminology here since I thought that more people are familiar with categorical parlance than with the order-theoretic one.